# Add a field to torchtext dataset like “apply” function in pandas dataframe

Tags: dataset, torchtext

In pandas dataframe, one could use the function “apply” to process the data frame and append the output as an extra column to the data frame. Does torchtext has a similar function of “apply” to insert a column to a tabular dataset? Thanks.